# Is it possible in Firestore to know the length of new docs which Recently added

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

**Flutter Firestore**

Is it possible in Firestore to know the number  of new docs which Recently added without the old once  in the same collection ?

well lets say user add 3 docs yesterday , then i knew the number by `docs.length` .. today user add 3 more new docs .. well again `docs.length` it will print 6 docs which is the total but i need to know the only 3 docs which are they new

i tried to use `docsChanged` too  this but bad result or maybe i cannot managed the code correctly

```
 value.docChanges.forEach((element) {
         FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.documentUid).doc(currentUser.uid).update({
           "countM":  element.newIndex
         });
       });
```

Is there a way to calculate only the new index which not been indexing b4

Comment: Basically you want to fetch docs added today? Or docs added since user's last visit?

Comment: new once , today

Comment: Do you have any field that stores date when the doc was added?

Comment: it is only to know the new docs index to use them as new messages as a counter  , this is the perfect way to do it either user has internet or lost the connection